# php json_array echo tweet text

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am attempting to echo a Tweet button in a table and have the tweet text from a json_array response.

The following code work unless the json response has a single quote(apostrophe) in it.

If the response has a single quote ( example  I'm unhappy) this breaks the tweet text and stops after the I

is there away to strip all single quoyes from an array? or is there a better way to do what I am trying to accomplish?

```
    echo "<table border='0'>";
    echo "<tr><td><a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button'{count} data-text='";
    echo $json_array["reasons"][0]["author_name"], "says ", $json_array["reasons"][0]["content"];
    echo " data-via='OnRecall' data-hashtags='OnRecall'>Tweet</a></td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>Name: </td><td>", $json_array["reasons"][0]["author_name"];
    echo " -> Liked: ", $json_array["reasons"][0]["like_count"], " times.</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td width= '20'></td><td>",  $json_array["reasons"][0]["content"];
    echo "</td></tr></table><p><hr></hr></p>";
```

So if $json_array["reasons"][0]["content"] has a single quote in it,  the tweet text stops at it.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function to accomplish this. With the `ENT_QUOTES` flag, this function will encode all quotes as HTML entities (`'` becomes `&#039;`) and also significantly reduce your vulnerability to [Cross-Site Scripting attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) -- this is especially important when the data you're displaying comes from an untrusted source (like someone else's Twitter feed):

```
$content = htmlspecialchars($json_array["reasons"][0]["author_name"], ENT_QUOTES)
    . "says "
     . htmlspecialchars($json_array["reasons"][0]["content"], ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<a ... data-text='$content'>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape all the single quotes in your string. You can use `str_replace()` function to replace all `'` to `\'`, like this:

```
$content = str_replace("'","\'",$json_array["reasons"][0]["content"]);
// now echo $content
```

Here's the reference:

- [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: Thank you, I tried this as well, but Twitter still didn't like the \'
but your answer has helped me with a different issue I was having.